# Code is still running past async function, instead of waiting for API to respond

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am working on a bot that retrieves data from an API. I originally was developing the bot in browser-side Javascript, but I am now transitioning to Node.js. I am having trouble with my async function. I want to wait for a response from the API to create an object and work with the data; however, the code continues, and I received an 'undefined error' for my obj variable.

```
async function doGetRequest(URL) {

const axios = require('axios');

let res = await axios.get(URL);

let data = res.data;
console.log(data);
}

function readBids(pairs) {
let i = 0;

let TrianglePair = {pair: [], price: [], typeTrade: "", tradeAmount: 0, highestProfit: ""};




//var URL = "https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/market/orderbook/level2_20?symbol=";

let tempVal;



for(i = 0; i < pairs.length; i ++) {

    
      
    let obj = doGetRequest('https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/market/orderbook/level2_20?symbol=SHIB-USDT');
    console.log(obj);

    tempVal = obj.bids[i][0];
    TrianglePair.pair[i] = pairs[i];
    TrianglePair.price[i] = tempVal;
    console.log(response);
    return TrianglePair

}
```

}

How can I wait for the API's response before continuing? Do I need to restructure the architecture of my code or is there another solution? Thanks!

Comment: doGetRequest returns a promise since it is an async function. You need to await that call too

Comment: You already did `console.log(obj);` - what output did you get? Did this not provide enough of a clue?